# Upload text file not working

Tags: php, html

I have a script that takes a text file and insert it to db. I have do the exacly script for xls,xlsx,csv.. and worked fine but with .txt file i get a error reading the file. Here is my code

```
//html form that uploads the file
<html>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>

//this is my php script
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $document = fopen($file,'r');
        $contents = fread($document, filesize($file));
        fclose($document);
        $contents = str_replace("\r\n","|",$contents);
        $contents = str_replace("\"","",$contents);
        $contents = explode("|",$contents);
        $contents = array_chunk($contents, 10);

        $count = 0;
        for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($contents);$i++){
            $categoria = $contents[$i][0];
            $ragsoc    = $contents[$i][1];
            $telefono  = $contents[$i][2];
            $via       = $contents[$i][3];
            $comune    = $contents[$i][4];
            $cap       = $contents[$i][5];
            $pro       = $contents[$i][6];
            $reg       = $contents[$i][7];
            $gas       = $contents[$i][8];
            $scadenza  = convert_date($contents[$i][9]);
            $query = "insert into tabela set
                categoria='".mysqli_real_escape_string($categoria)."',
                ragsoc='".mysqli_real_escape_string($ragsoc)."',
                telefono='".mysqli_real_escape_string($telefono)."',
                via='".mysqli_real_escape_string($via)."',
                comune='".mysqli_real_escape_string($comune)."',
                cap='".mysqli_real_escape_string($cap)."',
                pro='".mysqli_real_escape_string($pro)."',
                reg='".mysqli_real_escape_string($reg)."',
                gas='".mysqli_real_escape_string($gas)."',
                scadenza='".mysqli_real_escape_string($scadenza)."',
                data_ins='$data'";
            $result = mysqli_query($query);
            if(!$result){
                echo mysqli_error();
            }
            $count++;
            //echo $query;exit;
        }

        echo "Total records :".$count;
    }
```

The problem is that i cant read the file. If i put the file source like this

```
$file = "myfile.txt";
```

the script will work fine but when i point the script like this

```
$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

I get a emty array()

Comment: Your query is failing for a few reasons. Best to go read the manuals for those functions and checking for errors on PHP.

Comment: Thank Fred i know that the query has sam issues but i have to make it this way because boss wand it this way. The problem is with the file

Comment: You're welcome. However, the way you have it now and the way he/she wants it, will never work. Think "database connection" for the query and escape functions.

Comment: There is also nothing assigned to `$data`. So again; error checking via PHP and connect to the functions. There isn't' anything else I can add to my comments.

Comment: $data is a date('Y-m-d'); i have not post it to the question above but it is in the script

Comment: The problem was on my wamp configuration files.. Now its working